# What is the Excel Date Format to retain dates in this specific format?

Tags: excel, datetime

I am exporting the output of a `SQL` query into `Excel 365` and one of the columns contain `date` values.

My `SQl` query output displays those values as `2014-05-08 12:14:50.000`. I want to format this specific column in `Excel` so that it displays the values in its original format.

How can I do this in `Excel`?

Comment: Just confirming, do you already have the excel file with the date values, the only issue being that the format is not the same as the one in SQL?

Comment: Yes, I already have the excel file with the date values. It's just not showing in the same format as the SQL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the column you need to format, use format cells (you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and using custom formatting, use the following:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
```

And that should work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you bring the SQL data into Excel, it may automatically be converted to an Excel date/time value. Or you can specify on data import that the column should be converted to date/time.

If the date arrives as a text string, you can use the DateValue() function to convert the text string into an Excel date/time value.

The format is just presentation of the date/time value. Select from any of the standard formats or roll your own. Without knowing the original format, it is hard to suggest what custom format you need.

Mynda Treacy has a very good walk through here: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time-formatting